# how to convert viewmodel to accept any model in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC 4 application in which user can select a data source from a dropdownlist and based on the selection we search in the relevant table using Entity Framework. A data model is returned to the search results view. I have created a partial view for each source results as the fields are different in each data model. My code looks like this

```
@using SFRS.GazMatching.Web.Models
@model IPagedList<CentraladdrcdoQuery>

@Html.Partial("_SearchForm", searchFormViewModel)

<h4>Search Results</h4>

@if (ViewBag.IsCentralAddrcCDOQuery)
{
@Html.Partial("_CentraladdrcdoQuery", Model)
}

@if (ViewBag.IsLandbfsladdraddrcdoQuery)
{
@Html.Partial("_LandbfsladdraddrcdoQueries", Model)
 }
```

Just wondering if can convert this model to accept any data model `IPagedList<CentraladdrcdoQuery>` i.e. `IPagedList<T>` and T can of of type CentraladdrcdoQuery,LandbfsladdraddrcdoQuery etc and we can render the relevant partial view by checking the ViewBag value

Comment: You can use generics

Comment: I need to return entity framework entities as model to the view. All the entities have different fields. Not sure how can I convert those entities into Generic Interface

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. You've posted some code but not really described where it is falling short.

Comment: Currently I have to return `IEnumerable<CentraladdrcdoQuery>` from the controller to render the view which has the model `@model IPagedList<CentraladdrcdoQuery>` but what I m trying to do to return any model e.g. `IEnumerable<Query1>` or `IEnumerable<Query2>` etc and use the same view to accept the model and based on the ViewBag value I call the relevant partial view

Comment: As you have mentioned, you are bringing search results. Although results might come from different tables, I think you should have new model as SearchResult & irrespective of from which tables search results are coming SearchResult model should have common field. Like Result title, description....

Comment: @AK47 Brilliant direction. I have created SearchResultsModel with properties like `public IEnumerable<CentraladdrcdoQuery> centraladdrcdoQuery { get; set; }` and similarly added other data entities model and returning  this model to the view and passing the relevant property to the View. If you kindly add your comment as a solution then I will accept it. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you are bringing search results. Although results might come from different tables, I think you should have new model as SearchResult & irrespective of from which tables search results are coming SearchResult model should have common field. Like Result title, description....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by creating a new model SearchResultsModel, as below and added individual data model entities as properties. In the controller I retrieve the search results and set the property value based on the user selection of the source and return this model

```
public class SearchResultsModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CentraladdrcdoQuery> centraladdrcdoQuery { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LandbfsladdraddrcdoQuery> landbfsladdraddrcdoQuery { get; set; }
}
```

The view has the following markup

```
@model SearchResultsModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Search";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
SearchFormViewModel searchFormViewModel = new SearchFormViewModel();
}

@Html.Partial("_SearchForm", searchFormViewModel)
<h4>Search Results</h4>

@if (ViewBag.Source == "1")
{
@Html.Partial("_CentraladdrcdoQuery", Model.centraladdrcdoQuery)
}

@if (ViewBag.Source == "2")
{
@Html.Partial("_LandbfsladdraddrcdoQuery", Model.landbfsladdraddrcdoQuery)
}
```